# Pesuchah and Setumah between Third and Fourth Dibros

Tags: parashas-yisro, aseres-hadibros, vaeschanan

In Parshas Yisro, between the third and fourth commandments (20:7-8), there is a pesuchah, not found anywhere else in the Aseres HaDibros.

In Parshas Va'Eschanan, in fact, this Pesuchah is a Setumah, like the other Parshah breaks in that set of Dibros (5:11-12).

Why are there these discrepancies?